# ValueError at /pharmcare/patients-create/: "needs to have a value for field "id" before this many-to-many relationship can be used."

Tags: django, django-forms, django-templates, django-orm

Please help me with the Django app I am creating called `pharmcare` on the issue I am having. I have been stuck on this value-error for 2 days now, and I had researched how to sort it out when using the `ManyToMany` relationship including reading the Django docs. Still, I ended up getting None as total payment in the patients `http://127.0.0.1:8000/pharmcare/patient-list/` which is kind of weird in my second solution, and I believe I am missing something on my second solution. Please, I do want the total to be saved dynamically once the pharmacist has added the discount price and if there is no discount which I set to `null and blank=True`, I would want the previous total to be saved as well on pharmaceutical_care_plan table of my PostgreSQL.

Here is my model:

```py
class PharmaceuticalCarePlan(models.Model):

    class Meta:
        ordering = ['id']

    user = models.ForeignKey('songs.User', on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    pharmacist = models.ForeignKey(
        "Pharmacist", on_delete=models.SET_NULL, null=True, blank=True)
    organization = models.ForeignKey(
        'leads.UserProfile', on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    patients = models.ManyToManyField('Patient')
    patient_unique_code = models.CharField(
        max_length=20, null=True, blank=True)

    total_payment = models.PositiveBigIntegerField(null=True, blank=True)
    discount = models\
        .PositiveBigIntegerField(null=True, blank=True,
                                 help_text="discount given to patient,\
            perhaps due to his/her consistent loyalty strictly authorized by \
                management (if any).")
       # other codes 

    slug = models.SlugField(null=True, blank=True)

    date_created = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)

    def __str__(self) -> str:
        if self.monitoring_plan:
            
            return f'The  {self.monitoring_plan.frequency}'
        return "Frequency of monitoring plan was not provided, perhaps\
            you forgot to select the field in the form."
        

    def get_pharmcare_absolute_url(self):
        reverse("pharmcare:patients-detail",
                kwargs={"pk": self.pk})

    # error is coming from here
    def get_total(self) -> int:
        """ get's the total amount paid throughout the pharmcare cycle of the 
          patient."""

          total = 0
        # where the error is coming from according to django error-traceback (line 
          #  124 of my model)      
       for patient_list in self.patients.all():
            total += patient_list.get_total_charge()

            # check discount if any
            if self.discount is None:
                return patient_list.get_total_charge()

            total -= self.discount
            return total
  
    def get_total_when_no_discount(self) -> int:
        """ patient_pharmcare_summary = PharmaceuticalCarePlan.objects.filter(
            id=self.pk) """
        # pt_name = Patient.objects.get(id=self.pk)
        total = 0
       # for patient_list in patient_pharmcare_summary:
        for patient_list in self.patients.all():
            total = patient_list.get_total_charge()
            return total
       # wrote some bunch of other codes here not useful to this question


  # Here is what I tried as my 2nd solution in the model for id to be assigned to the
  # `ManyToMany relationship column: patients`. However, the Value-error disappeared
  # but it returns None as a value from db. :-(
  def get_total(self) -> int:
        """ get's the total amount paid throughout the pharmcare
        cycle of the patient."""
       # pt_name, created = Patient.objects.get_or_create(id=self.pk)
        patient_pharmcare_summary = PharmaceuticalCarePlan.objects.filter(id=self.pk)
        #
        total = 0
        for patient_lists in patient_pharmcare_summary:

            for patient_list in patient_lists.patients.all():
                patient_ = patient_list
                
                total += patient_.get_total_charge()

                if self.discount:
                    total -= self.discount
                    return total
                
                return patient_list.get_total_charge()
```

Here is my View:

````
class PatientSummaryCreateView(OrganizerPharmacistLoginRequiredMixin, CreateView):
    """ Handles request-response cycle made by the admin/pharmacists
    to create a patient"""

    template_name = 'pharmcare/pharmaceutical_care_plans/patients-create.html'
 
    form_class = PharmaceuticalCarePlanModelForm

    def get_queryset(self, slug, *args, **kwargs):
        user = self.request.user
        patients = get_object_or_404(Patient, slug=slug)

        if user.is_organizer:
            self.queryset = PharmaceuticalCarePlan.objects.filter(
                organization=user.userprofile)

        else:
            self.queryset = PharmaceuticalCarePlan.objects.filter(
                organization=user.pharmacist.organization)

            self.queryset = self.queryset.filter(
                pharmacist__user=self.request.user)

        return self.queryset

    def form_valid(self, form: BaseModelForm) -> HttpResponse:
        user = self.request.user

        form = form.save(commit=False)

        form.user = user
        form.organization = user.userprofile
       
        form.patient_unique_code = generate_patient_unique_code()
        form.slug = slug_modifier()
        form.total_payment = form.get_total()
        form.save()
        
        

        if reminder_time():  # show this from 11hr to 12hr everyday
            messages.warning(self.request,
                             f"""Please Pharm {user.username.title()}, 
                             be cautious of given 
                     discount to customers! Any discount must be authorized by the
                     management.""")
        return super(PatientSummaryCreateView, self).form_valid(form)

    def get_success_url(self) -> str:
        return reverse('pharmcare:patients')

```py

Here is my Form:

```py

class PharmaceuticalCarePlanModelForm(forms.ModelForm):
    """ Pharmceutical care form that handles user input and validations """
    class Meta:
        model = PharmaceuticalCarePlan
        fields = [
            'patients',
            'has_improved',
            'progress_note',
            'medication_changes',
            'analysis_of_clinical_problem',
            'monitoring_plan',
            'follow_up_plan',
            'discount'
        ]
````

Here is my template: patients.html:

```
    
            <tbody>
             {% for patient_qs in patient_list %}
              <tr
                class="bg-white border-b dark:bg-gray-800 dark:border-gray-700 
                hover:bg-gray-50 dark:hover:bg-gray-600"
              >

                 <td class="w-4 p-4">
                    <div class="flex items-center">
                      <span>{{forloop.counter }}</span>
                    </div>
                  </td>
                {% for pt in patient_qs.patients.all %}
                  <td class="px-6 py-4">{{ pt.get_full_name }}</td>
                {% endfor %}
                      {% comment %}  deleted some bunch of codes here which are not 
                     useful based on the question {% endcomment %}

                  {% if patient_qs.discount > 1 %}
                  <td class="px-6 py-4">₦{{ patient_qs.total }}</td>
                  {% else %}
                  <td class="px-6 py-4">₦{{patient_qs.get_total_when_no_discount }}</td>
                  {%endif %}
           
                  <td class="px-6 py-4"> {{ patient_qs.date_created }} in UTC </td>
            
                  <td class="flex items-center px-6 py-4">
                    <a
                      href="
                      {% url "pharmcare:patients-detail" patient_qs.pk %} 
                          
                      "
                      class="pr-2 font-medium text-blue-600 dark:text-blue-500 hover:underline"
                      >For Further Details</a
                    >
                  </td>
            </tr>
            </tbody>
            
          {% endfor %}
```

Thank you.

Comment: Did you get it to work or still have the problem?

Answer (score 0):

```
class PatientSummaryCreateView(OrganizerPharmacistLoginRequiredMixin, CreateView):
    """ Handles request-response cycle made by the admin/pharmacists
    to create a patient"""

    template_name = 'pharmcare/pharmaceutical_care_plans/patients-create.html'
    queryset = PharmaceuticalCarePlan.object.all()
    form_class = PharmaceuticalCarePlanModelForm
```

add **queryset = PharmaceuticalCarePlan.object.all()** to the View

Comment: I isolated using generalized queryset class because I want to filter the authorized users using get_queryset(). Thanks for your help, and that doesn't solve the problem either.